# Extracting a DIV's content using Sitemesh Decorators

Tags: java, jsp, decorator, sitemesh

I would like to know how I can extract the content of a specific DIV using decorators, instead of using `<decorator:body />` which will fetch all the content inside the `<body>` tag.

Comment: Not actually a sitemesh solution, but if you want it working really fast you can do it with jQuery with something like this `$(document).ready(function() {$("#inner-div").prependTo("#content-wrapper");});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NB Black Sensei has posted a better answer below.

I don't think this is possible. Sitemesh is a pretty basic templating system that has very few tags - five in all. There's a full list here [decorator taglib](http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/tags.html#decorator:getProperty)

You might want to look at another templating system if you need that level of control.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible with the version 2.4.2 of sitemesh that i'm using.Found the anwser on  [christian grobmeier](http://www.grobmeier.de/sitemesh-2-decorating-from-divs-instead-of-body-21042011.html)  so here is my `sitemesh.xml`

```
<sitemesh>
  <property name="decorators-file" value="/WEB-INF/decorators.xml"/>
  <excludes file="${decorators-file}"/>

  <page-parsers>
    <parser content-type="text/html" class="com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.parser.HTMLPageParser"/>
  </page-parsers>

  <page-parsers>
    <parser content-type="text/html" class="com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.multipass.DivExtractingPageParser"/>
  </page-parsers>

  <decorator-mappers>
    <mapper class="com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.mapper.ConfigDecoratorMapper">
        <param name="config" value="${decorators-file}"/>
    </mapper>
  </decorator-mappers>
</sitemesh>
```

here is a snippet of my mainlayout.jsp

```
  <div id="container" style=" padding-top: 60px; ">
            <div id="leftbar">

                <div style="height:400px;">
                    <img src="<spring:url value='/images/Logo.png'/>" class="logo"/>
                </div>

                <decorator:getProperty property="div.side-menu"/>
                <%--<decorator:body />--%>
            </div>
            <div>
                <decorator:getProperty property="div.top"  />
            </div>
            <div>
                <decorator:getProperty property="div.content"  />
            </div>
        </div>
```

snippet of home.ftl (using freemarker)

```
<div id="side-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="/home">All</a></li>
      <#list genre as gen >
        <li><a href="/category?cat=${gen}">${gen}</a></li>
     </#list>
</ul>
</div>


<div id="top">
  <ul id="slider" class="architectorSlider">
     <li>
        <img src="<@spring.url '/images/slide_1.jpg'/>" alt="" class="slide-image"/>
        <img src="<@spring.url '/images/slider/timthumbf014.jpg'/>?src=<@spring.url '/images/slide_1.jpg' />&amp;w=100&amp;h=42&amp;zc=1"
             alt="" class="slide-thumbnail"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

i hope this can get you going if it's not too late :D

Comment: This is not right. You should REPLACE `HtmlPageParser` with `DivExtractingPageParser`. Otherwise weird things can happen. Note also your XML is poorly formed, there should not be two `<page-parsers>` sections.

Answer (score 0):

SiteMesh comes with com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.multipass.DivExtractingPageParser.  It's limited in functionality; it only extracts the divs one level below the body.

Comment: That's a good thing...otherwise sitemesh will mess with any div that has an id. Wrapping a div in another one without an id will protect it.